# Arithmetic/Geometric series calculator

Tags: python, python-3.x, math-expression-eval

I've written a small program that calculates Arithmetic and Geometric Partial Sums. I'd like feedback on anything possible, since I intend on writing a cheatsheet that encapsulates all PreCalculus equations.

**partial_sum.py**

```
"""
This is a program that calculates arithmetic and geometric
partial sums

"""

from fractions import Fraction

def find_an(parsed_series):
    """
    Finds an in the passed parsed arithmetic series

    :param parsed_series: The series to be analyzed

    """
    for i, _ in enumerate(parsed_series):
        if parsed_series[i] == ".":
            return int(parsed_series[i + 1])
    return None


def arithmetic_partial_sum(series):
    """
    Returns the partial sum of an arithmetic series

    Formula:
        S = n( (a1 + an) / 2 )

    Find an:
        an = a1 + (n - 1)d

    Find n:
        n = 1 + ( (an - a1) / d )

    :param series: Arithmetic series to solve

    """

    series = series.split("+")

    a1 = int(series[0])
    d = int(series[1]) - a1
    an = find_an(series)
    n = 1 + ((an - a1) / d)
    S = n * ((a1 + an) / 2)

    return S

def geometric_partial_sum(series):
    """
    Returns the partial sum of the geometric series

    :param series: Geometric series to solve

    Formula:
        S = (a1 * (1 - (r ** n))) / (1 - r)

    """

    series = series.split("+")

    a1 = int(series[0])
    r = int(series[1]) / a1
    n = len(series)
    S = (a1 * (1 - (r ** n))) / (1 - r)

    return str(Fraction(S).limit_denominator())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    A_SERIES = "3+7+11+15+.+99"
    G_SERIES = f"3+1+{1/3}+{1/9}+{1/27}+{1/81}"
    print(arithmetic_partial_sum(A_SERIES))
    print(geometric_partial_sum(G_SERIES))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`find_an()` looks like an internal function, used by `arithmetic_partial_sum()`.  If it is not for external use, it should be named with a leading underscore, to suggest it is private.

---

`arithmetic_partial_sum()` appears to handle only integer values, yet it return a floating-point value (`1275.0` in the built-in example).  It should return an integer, since it is adding up integers.  Use the Python3.x integer-division operator: `//`.

```
    n = 1 + (an - a1) // d
    S = n * (a1 + an) // 2
```

Or, not assume the terms are integer, and use `float(...)` instead.

---

`geometric_partial_sum()` fails if the first 2 values are not  `int` values:

```
>>> geometric_partial_sum(f"1+{1/3}+{1/9}+{1/27}+{1/81}")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    geometric_partial_sum(f"1+{1/3}+{1/9}+{1/27}+{1/81}")
  File "...\partial_sum.py", line 63, in geometric_partial_sum
    r = int(series[1]) / a1
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0.3333333333333333'
```

You should convert the terms to floating-point values, not integers:

```
    a1 = float(series[0])
    r = float(series[1]) / a1
```

---

`find_an()` assumes \$a_n\$ is immediately after the `'.'` term, so will fail with:

```
arithmetic_partial_sum("3+7+11+15+.+95+99")
arithmetic_partial_sum("3+7+11+15+19")
```

Why not just retrieve the last term?

```
def find_an(parsed_series):
    return int(parsed_series[-1])
```

Now the following all succeed and return the correct values

```
arithmetic_partial_sum("3+7+11+15+.+95+99")
arithmetic_partial_sum("3+7+11+15+...+95+99")
arithmetic_partial_sum("3+7+11+15+19")
```

---

The `"""docstrings"""` for `arithmetic_partial_sum()` and `geometric_partial_sum()` appear unhelpful.  For example:

```
>>> help(arithmetic_partial_sum)
Help on function arithmetic_partial_sum in module __main__:

arithmetic_partial_sum(series)
    Returns the partial sum of an arithmetic series

    Formula:
        S = n( (a1 + an) / 2 )

    Find an:
        an = a1 + (n - 1)d

    Find n:
        n = 1 + ( (an - a1) / d )

    :param series: Arithmetic series to solve
```

The function is not returning `an` or `n`.  Even the formula is not particularly helpful.  `"""docstrings"""` should tell a user how to use the function.  For example (adding Python 3.6 type hints as well):

```
def arithmetic_partial_sum(series:str) -> int:
    """
    Returns the sum of an arithmetic series

    Example:
        s = arithmetic_partial_sum("1+3+5+.+99")  # returns 2500

    :param series: A string representing the arithmetic series to solve
    """
```

Now type `help(arithmetic_partial_sum)`:

```
>>> help(arithmetic_partial_sum)
Help on function arithmetic_partial_sum in module __main__:

arithmetic_partial_sum(series: str) -> int
    Returns the sum of an arithmetic series

    Example:
        s = arithmetic_partial_sum("1+3+5+.+99")  # returns 2500

    :param series: A string representing the arithmetic series to solve
```

The user is told the function takes a string and returns an integer.  The format of the string should be clear from the example.

Answer (score 4):

One thing to also include is the fact that it also doesn't support series in which each term alternates between positive and negative as the `series = series.split("+")`

For example in an arithmetic series like `5+3+1-1-3` with a common difference of -2, 
the way the `series = series.split("+")` is set up, will make it detect `1-1-3` as a single term.

And in geometric terms, for example: `9-3+1-(1/3)+(1/9)`, it will again fail to detect the `-` and mistake `9-3` and `1-(1/3)` as complete terms.

A viable solution is to separate every term whether negative or not by a `+`.
Using the two examples above:

- Arithmetic: `"5+3+1+-1+-3"`
- Geometric:  `f"9+-3+1+-{1/3}+{1/9}"`